# How to add a dependency to a module and import the static files (public folder)

Tags: node.js, module

I have a NodeJS project and need to add a dependency to another module with some static contents in the public folder, such as js libraries, css, etc.

I want to automatically link the public folder to also use all the static contents from the other module. Is it possible?

Since I'm going to maintain both projects, I don't want to copy/paste the public folder from the main project, because every change I make on the main project I should copy/paste over and over again (this is a terrible idea).

The dependent module will also have a public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create npm module of you public folder, upload it to github, then you can create dependency of this folder, install it by npm install and `ln -s ./public ./node_modules/whatever_your_module_is_called` or even to bind this folder as public inside your project